# Joining Tables and Data for a Football/Soccer Website

Tags: php, mysql

Im learning PHP and currently creating a website for a local football club. 
They have multiple teams at various age groups. I have created a database of 'team' which has all of the information with regards to team name, which league, team photo, training information. I also have a 'coaches' table which as name, dob, qualifications, contact info. How would i add information to be displayed in a table that link the two.

So in 'coach1' and 'coach2' it will display the name of the two coaches linked to that club.

I am thinking that when i create a new coach (via form) they will be able to select the team from the database via a dropdown box.

what would be the best way to link this together, when a coach is signing up, selecting their team from the dropdown. They are linked. but some teams have two coaches, im guessing the second coach selecting the team would then overwrite the previous, how would you add this as an additional coach? Im thinking that i would add an additional drop down that would fill in 'role' column with either Manager or Assistant, i would then have to add field where 'SELECT coach WHERE role = Assistant AND id = $id'

```
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Team Name</th>
                <th>Training</th>
                <th>League</th>
                <th>Coaches</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<?php
    $no     = 1;
    $total  = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($team)) 
    {
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'." u".$row['age_group']." ".$row['team_name'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['training_day'].", ".$row['location']." at ".$row['training_time'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['league']." - ".$row['match_day'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['coach1'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['coach2'].'</td>
                <td><a href="viewapp.php?id='.($row['team_id']).'" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-xs">View</a></td> 
                </tr>';    
        $no++;
    }?>
</tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: By linking, what do you mean? Database side? Back end side? Front end side?

Comment: i think ERR0 gets my drift. basically 2 database tables which link the coach and the team.

Comment: Its a many to many situation, so have a `coach` (links user as a coach) and `team_coach` (links coach to team) table, then use a JOIN to link them. Many coaches can be on many teams then. I guess you're just using columns and not normalising.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but do not concatenate arbitrary data directly into the context of HTML without escaping it first!  At best, you'll be introducing invalid HTML.  At worst, you open yourself up to some bad security issues.  Always use `htmlspecialchars()` around data you're concatenating into HTML.

Comment: thanks brad, im going to go through all the security once i have the page complete.

Comment: Just have one column for the adviser (their id) and another column for their role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's DB design only, let's explode the problem.

You have coaches and teams.

---

## Case 1 : A coach can belong to 1 team

A **unique** coach belongs to a **unique** team (this is a 1,1 relation)

A **unique** team can have **one or many** coaches. (this is a 1,n relation)

We can draw a relational schema of those entities this way :

> [coach] -(1, 1)-> [coach_team] <-(1, n)- [team]

In this kind of relation, the foreign key of the team will be stored in the `coach` table

As exemple, I have 2 teams, *foo* and *bar*. And 3 coaches, *John Smith*, *Jane Doe* and *Zinedine Zidane*. John and Jane are the coaches of the team *foo* and Zidane is the coach of the team bar.

Let's consider the table `team` has 2 fields, `id` and `name` and the table `coach` has 3 fields, `id`, `name` and `team_id`. We can build the tables this way :

```
CREATE TABLE team
(
  id INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE coach
(
  id INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  team_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(team_id) REFERENCES team(id)
);

INSERT INTO team VALUES (default, "foo"), (default, "bar");

INSERT INTO coach VALUES (default, "John Smith", 1), (default, "Jane Doe", 1), (default, "Zinedine Zidane", 2);
```

How do I know who are the coaches of the team *foo* ? Using a `JOIN` on the foreign key :

```
SELECT t.name AS "Team name", c.name AS "Coach name"
FROM team t
INNER JOIN coach c
ON c.team_id = t.id
WHERE t.name = "foo";
```

**Result**

```
| Team name | Coach name |
+-----------+------------+
| foo       | John Smith |
| foo       | Jane Doe   |
```

How do I know what is the team coached by Zidane? Using the same query, only the `WHERE` clause changes :

```
SELECT t.name AS "Team name", c.name AS "Coach name"
FROM team t
INNER JOIN coach c
ON c.team_id = t.id
WHERE c.name = "Zinedine Zidane";
```

**Result**

```
| Team name | Coach name      |
+-----------+-----------------+
| bar       | Zinedine Zidane |
```

You can try it yourself on [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4k8N4jmV1DWz7cMSgkg1Ch/0)

---

## Case 2 : A coach can belong to n team

A **unique** coach belongs to **one or many** teams (this is a 1,n relation)

A **unique** team can have **one or many** coaches. (this is a 1,n relation)

We can draw a relational schema of those entities this way :

> [coach] -(1, n)-> [coach_team] <-(1, n)- [team]

In this kind of relation, a new table `coach_team` is needed, where both foreign keys of the coach and the team will be stored. To avoid duplication of the couples coach/team, I prefer declaring the `PRIMARY KEY` as a composition of both foreign keys.

As exemple, I have 3 teams, *foo*, *bar* and *team 42*. And 3 coaches, *John Smith*, *Jane Doe* and *Zinedine Zidane*. John and Jane are the coaches of the team *foo* and Zidane is the coach of the team bar and the team 42 has Zidane and Jane as coach.

**Coach**

```
 id | name
----+-----------------
 1  | John Smith
 2  | Jane Doe
 3  | Zinedine Zidane
```

**Team**

```
 id | name
----+--------
 1  | foo
 2  | bar
 3  | team 42
```

**coach_team**

```
 coach_id | name_id
----------+---------
 1        | 1
 2        | 1
 3        | 2
 2        | 3
 3        | 3
```

**Table creations**

```
CREATE TABLE team
(
  id INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE coach
(
  id INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE coach_team
(
  coach_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
  team_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(coach_id) REFERENCES coach(id),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(team_id) REFERENCES team(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (coach_id, team_id)
);

INSERT INTO team VALUES (default, "foo"), (default, "bar"), (default, "Team 42");

INSERT INTO coach VALUES (default, "John Smith"), (default, "Jane Doe"), (default, "Zinedine Zidane");

INSERT INTO coach_team VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3);
```

How do I get the coaches of the team *foo* ? I query the team, `JOIN` on the reference table, `coach_team`, then another `JOIN` on the table coach.

```
SELECT t.name AS "Team name", c.name AS "Coach name"
FROM team t
INNER JOIN coach_team ct
ON ct.team_id = t.id
INNER JOIN coach c
ON ct.coach_id = c.id
WHERE t.name="foo";
```

**Result**

```
| Team name | Coach name |
+-----------+------------+
| foo       | John Smith |
| foo       | Jane Doe   |
```

How do I know what is the team coached by Zidane? Using the same query, only the `WHERE` clause changes :

```
SELECT t.name AS "Team name", c.name AS "Coach name"
FROM team t
INNER JOIN coach_team ct
ON ct.team_id = t.id
INNER JOIN coach c
ON ct.coach_id = c.id
WHERE c.name="Zinedine Zidane";
```

**Result**

```
| Team name | Coach name      |
+-----------+-----------------+
| bar       | Zinedine Zidane |
| Team 42   | Zinedine Zidane |
```

---

You can try it yourself on [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/52TfASdqSYBpncRMmW99K5/0)

Comment: thats great Thanks Cid.

Just another addidtion question... what if a coached also coached an addition team (so a coach, coaches 2 different teams.)

Comment: @AndyTerry Can it be the case for your application?

Comment: Cid that is perfect mate. i appreciate the time and effort into the answer. 
2 or 3 coaches in our club do coach mutliple teams within the club. eg steve coaches the under 13s and 15s.

so this is exactly what i was needing clarifying.. appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome :) Hint : Since a coach can manage many teams, when creating a new coach, a dropdown isn't the best choice (1 team to select) but checkboxes might suits better your needs (multiples teams can be selected)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreign key between the two tables to connect the information. In example, add a column named something like team_id in the 'coaches' table. This column should have the id of the team from the 'team' table.

Then, when you register a new coach in a form, you can use the id as the value from the dropdown.

Comment: thats exactly what im looking for. As i will be adding players also i would also need to link those to the team table. 

what would the query look like, i know how to do simple queries, not dealt with joins as of yet.

Comment: when a coach is signing up, selecting their team from the dropdown. They are linked.

but some teams have two coaches, im guessing the second coach selecting the team would then overwrite the previous, how would you add this as an additional coach?

Comment: As I said, you could add a column in the coaches table, so the structure would be something like:
name, dob, qualifications, contact info, team_id
where the team_id should be the id of the team in the team table.
Then in your schema for signing up coaches, you would have a dropdown something like this (fill it with the data from the DB):
    <select>
         <option value="team_id_1">Name of team 1</option>
         <option value="team_id_2">Name of team 2</option>
    </select>
And then you can use the team_id_x value in the INSERT statement